# How to populate a textbox based on dropdown selection in MVC..?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hi I have created a table and connected it to MVC project through ADO.NET entity. 
After connecting I added the controller for the entity and it creates a set of cshtml files in VIEW folder in MVC project. 
But now What I need is to create a dropdownlist and textbox.
I created the dropdownlist in a cshtml file and also wriiten the logic for it in the CONTROLLER. 
I can also create TEXTBOXES,but i'm facing the problem of poulating TEXTBOX based on the dropdownlist selection.

My Model auto generated by VS 2012 is

```
 public partial class Plan_S  

    {

        public int PlanId_PK { get; set; }
        public string PlanNames { get; set; }
        public string Hours { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller  for displaying dropdownlist is 
`

```
 public class dropdownController : Controller
    {


        private PivotEntities db = new PivotEntities();

        //
        // GET: /dropdown/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.plannames = new SelectList(db.Plan_S, "PlanId_PK", "PlanNames");

            return View();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
        public ActionResult ddl()
        {
            return View(new Plan_S());
        }

    }`
```

My view.cshtml for displaying dropdownlist is

`

```
@model Pivot.Models.Plan_S
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


<div>   

    @Html.DropDownList("PlanNames", "--select--")

</div>
```

`

Now When I select an item in the dropdownlist, it should automatically populate the corresponding value in the table.
Here in my code, Plan_S table is autogenrated as Plan_S MODEL Class. But in Database I have set of values for these columns in table.

```
eg..)     PlanId_PK  |   PlanNames  |    Hours
              1           Plan1          1hrs
              2           Plan2          2hrs
              3           Plan3          3hrs
```

Here in this Plan_S table,

PlanNames column is populated in the DROPDOWNLIST,
When I select the Plan1 in DDL it should populate the texbox as 1hrs

When I select the Plan2 in DDL it should populate the textbox as 2hrs.

This is the logic i need and I can do this in asp webforms but it is tricky in MVC.

I think that Jquery is needed for it.......

Please help me, I had spent hours in finding this logic....

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, let's create a View Model to hold these things:

```
public class PlanViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Plans { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your controller action let's build the Model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new PlanViewModel();

    model.Plans = db.Plan_S
        .Select(p => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = p.Hours,
            Text = p.PlanNames
        })
        .ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

Then in your View, do:

```
@model Pivot.Models.Plan_S
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<div>   
    @Html.DropDownList("PlanNames", Model.Plans, "--select--")
    <input id="planHours" type="text" />
</div>
```

Then you'll need to do the following in jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[name='PlanNames']").change(function () {
            $("#planHours").val($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi mattytommo I can't understand the CurrentPlan in the method Index()...Please help me on that part...

Comment: @user2309770 What is the purpose of your page? Is it to edit a plan, create a plan? Or just show information?

Comment: On clicking Plan1 in the dropdownlist, textbox should be populated with corresponding value in the table..and here it is, on clicking Plan1, the textbox should be filled as 1hrs as shown above in my question..

Comment: mattytommo My page just shows the details or information for the selected item in the dropdownlist...Thanks in advance

Comment: @user2309770 Check my updated edit. I thought you were editing a plan not just showing information. New code will provide you with that.

Comment: mattytomo for editing the plan, how to use CurrentPlan in method Index(). I cant understand what CurrentPlan is...?...It may be a silly question..please help on that...

Comment: @user2309770 My fault I didn't mean to leave that in. Check now I've taken it out.

Comment: @user2309770 No problems! Glad I could help :)

Comment: Hi Mattytommo..In the above table Plan_S I'm adding another column named as PlanCost...Now I need to populate the two Textboxes for the columns Hours and PlanCost on selecting the dropdownlist....Please advise me on that..Thanks in advance

Comment: @user2309770 In your controller method when it's populating the `SelectList` change `Value = p.Hours,` to be `Value = p.Hours + " " + p.PlanCost,` that should do it.

Comment: Hi mattytommo..I replaced p.Hours with p.Hours + " " + p.PlanCost and in Jquery i did this for displaying another text box for PlanCost....$("[name='PlanNames']").change(function () {
            $("#planHours").val($(this).val());
            $("#planCost").val($(this).val());

Comment: @user2309770 I'm guessing you get both hours and cost in both yeah?

Comment: Hi mattytommo...till now I was struggling with that....please advise me on that issue.Thanks in advance...

Comment: I got idea for editing the textboxes but dont know how to populate two textboxes on selecting a DDL....Kindly adivse me on that issue...Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: @user2309770 Sorry just seen this, have you got both the cost and hours in the `value` of the dropdown list (are they there when you look in the output HTML?)

Comment: @mattytommo..I used Json to return cost and hours..Now I have added a delete button and when I click on this button the dropdown selected value and corresponding values in textboxes should be deleted...Kindly advise me on that...?

Comment: @mattytommo....Please see this link for my another question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832461/how-to-change-a-dropdownlist-to-a-editable-textbox-on-clicking-edit-button-in-mv , in which the Json used to  display the textboxes,EDITING and Saving has been done....Now I need is to delete the selected item.....

Comment: Thanks for your help on 2013 which is very crucial for me(first task given to me in my first job) and still I remember how you helped me as an eye-opener. Thank you so much. Tried to reach you through Linkedin but your profile is not available and god bless you.

Comment: @RajeshKannan No problems at all! Thank you for letting me know about my LinkedIn - it's actually https://www.linkedin.com/in/mathewthompson1/ (have updated my profile too) :)