# How to change a DropdownList to a editable textbox on Clicking EDIT button in MVC...?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to change my dropdownlist to editable textbox on clicking Edit button. Here I have a Dropdownlist in my CSHTML file, and When i select a value in DDL the textbox populates corresponding value from the table.

here is my model

This Plan_S Model class is autogenerated by VS when I connect the table from database to MVC with ADO.NET Entity

```
public partial class Plan_S
    {
        public int PlanId_PK { get; set; }
        public string PlanNames { get; set; }
        public string Hours { get; set; }
        public string PlanCost{ get; set;}
```

public
        }

This class is created for listing the class Plan_S

```
public class PlanViewModel
    {

        public List<SelectListItem> Plans { get; set; }        
    }
```

My controller is

```
public class dropdownController : Controller
    {


        private PivotEntities db = new PivotEntities();

        //
        // GET: /dropdown/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new PlanViewModel();

            //model.Plan = CurrentPlan; //Replace this with the current plan you're editing
            model.Plans = db.Plan_S
                .Select(p => new SelectListItem
                {

                    Value = p.Hours,                   
                    Text = p.PlanNames

                })
                .ToList();

            return View(model);
        }
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
}
```

My View file for displaying the dropdownlist,TextBox,Edit button and Save button.

```
@model Pivot.Models.PlanViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<table>

    <tr id="ddl">

        <td>@Html.Label("Select Plan : ") </td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("PlanNames", Model.Plans, "--select--") </td>

    </tr>
    <tr id="editplan">
        <td>@Html.Label("Edit Plan : ")</td>
        <td><input id="plannames" type="text" /></td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.Label("Hours  :")</td>
        <td><input id="planHours" type="text" /></td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.Label("Edit  :")</td>
        <td><input id="Button1" type="button" value="Edit" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.Label("Save Changes :")</td>
        <td><input id="savebutton" type="submit" value="Save" /></td>        
    </tr>
</table>




<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[name='PlanNames']").change(function () {
            $("#planHours").val($(this).val());
        });
        $("#plannames").val($(this).val(""));
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#editplan").hide();
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            $("#ddl").hide();
            $("#editplan").show();
        });
        $("#savebutton").click(function () {
            $("#editplan").hide();
            $("#ddl").show();
        });


    });
</script>
```

My Table Plan_S looks like this:

```
  PlanId_PK   |    PlanNames    |     Hours     |      PlanCost

      1              Plan1             1hrs              $10
      2              Plan2             2hrs              $20
      3              Plan3             3hrs              $30
```

Here What I need is, When selecting dropdownlist from PlanNmes.

i.e.,)when selecting Plan2 in DDL, there are two textboxes, one should be populated with corresponding value from Hours and the another textbox should be populated from PlanCost.

When I click the Edit button the dropdown and the other two textboxes should be converted to be editable textbox and after that i should edit the plannames,plnacost,hours and
then when I click the save button it should be saved to the Plan_S.

I am trying this with the JQuery...

As I'm new to MVC I got confused......

Please advise me on that......

Thanks in Advance....:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires quite a bit of tinkering with ajax. Hope you get the idea.

I'd just populate the dropdownlist with SelectListItems where Value is the primary key of Plan_S like you would normally do. This allows scalability to the code incase your Plan_S expands and you'll need more edit fields:

```
model.Plans = db.Plan_S
            .Select(p => new SelectListItem
            {

                Value = p.PlanId_PK,                   
                Text = p.PlanNames

            })
            .ToList();
```

In html, add a hidden field for the id so we know what plan we are editing at the moment. We also need to save the plancost so it won't be null on update. Note that I also use class to hide plan fields so we have correct markup when hiding multiple rows:

```
<tr id="ddl">
    <td>Select plan</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownList("PlanNames", Model.Plans, "--select--") </td>
</tr>
<tr class="editplanfield">

    <td>@Html.Label("Edit Plan : ")</td>
    <td><input id="plannames" type="text" />
        <input type="hidden" id="planid"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="plancost"/>
    </td>        
</tr>
<tr class="editplanfield">
    <td>@Html.Label("Hours  :")</td>
    <td><input id="planHours" type="text" /></td>        
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>@Html.Label("Edit  :")</td>
    <td><input id="editbutton" type="button" value="Edit" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>@Html.Label("Save Changes :")</td>
    <td><input id="savebutton" type="submit" value="Save" /></td>        
</tr>
```

Then on editbutton click, we request the selected plan from server and fill the editfields:

```
$("#editbutton").click(function () {
        $("#ddl").hide();
        $(".editplanfield").show();
        // Request plan of selected id from server
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetPlan")', { planId: $("[name='PlanNames']").val() }, function (plan) {
            // Fill the fields according to the Jsondata we requested
            $("#planid").val(plan["PlanId_PK"]); 
            $("#plannames").val(plan["PlanNames"]);
            $("#planHours").val(plan["Hours"]);
            $("#plancost").val(plan["PlanCost"]);
            });
    });
```

Here is the server side controller code for the request:

```
    public JsonResult GetPlan(int planId)
    {
        var plan = db.Plan_S.Find(planId);
        return Json(plan, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now we need to save changes without postback so we need more ajax:

```
$("#savebutton").click(function () {
        // Parse the plan from fields
        var plan = new Object();
        plan.PlanId_PK = $("#planid").val();
        plan.PlanNames = $("#plannames").val();
        plan.Hours = $("#planHours").val();
        plan.PlanCost = $("#plancost").val()
        // Post it to server
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: "@Url.Action("UpdatePlan")",
            success: function (result)
            {
                //Postback success
                $(".editplanfield").hide();
                $("#ddl").show();
            },
            data: plan,
            accept: 'application/json'
        });
    });
```

Then on serverside we need the action to update the plan:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UpdatePlan(Plan_S plan)
    {
        /*  Update the plan in database */
        /* Just return something for now */
        return Json("Success");
    }
```

Comment: Hi Sormii..In the GetPlan() Method, how to fetch the data from database....By using Linq or some other way...please give some idea...

Comment: Thanks....In UpdatePlan() method, for updating the database I wrote this...db.Entry(plan).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();    Is that right...?

Comment: Yup that's the way to do it.

Comment: Hi Sormii..When i declared the Value = p.PlanId_PK it says, that it cannot implicitly convert int into string...What is the problem in that...?...Please advise me on that advise...

Comment: Hi Sormii..it doesn't work...Textboxes are getting populated when I click the dropdownlist....Can you please advise me on that issue...

Comment: Sorry Sormii...Textboxes are not getting populated when i select an item in the dropdownlist...Please advise me on that issue.....Thanks in advance....:)

Comment: They are populated when you click edit. You can move the getJson request into $("[name='PlanNames']").change if you want. As for the string thing, you can convert it to string as in p.PlanId_PK.ToString()

Comment: @sormii..I did converting it to string p.PlanId.ToString()...But when i build the project it is throwing the error like this.......**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression**.

Comment: @sormii...it works great....:) for converting it to string i used this....**Value=SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)q.PlanId_PK)**......Thanks...:)

Comment: @sormii..Now i have added a DELETE button and What I need is, when clicking Edit button the delete button will be shown...On CLICKING the delete button the selected item should be deleted and should be updated in the table.....Please advise me on that...Thanks in advance....

Comment: Post the value of planid via ajax on deletebutton click, and on serverside receive it with JsonResult Delete(int planId) where you delete it from the database. Similar to update, I'm sure you can handle it :)

Comment: For Deleting I did this in controller.....public JsonResult DeletePlan(int planid)
        {
            Plan_S plan_s = db.Plan_S.Find(planid);
            var plan = db.Plan_S.Remove(plan_s);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(plan,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Comment: In View I added.... $("#deletebutton").click(function () {$.ajax({
                type: "POST", url: "@Url.Action("DeletePlan")",
                success: function (result) {
                    $(".editplanfield").hide();
                    $("#ddl").show();
                },
                data: plan,
                accept:'application/json'
            
            });
            
        });

Comment: @sormii..Isn't right...I'm not clear with that..When I click the delete button there is no change...kindly advise me on that...Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: @sormii...I did this in my On clicking Delete button event in jquery..... var planid = $("[name='PlanNames']").val();
            
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", url: "@Url.Action("DeletePlan")",
            
                    
                    success: function (result) {
                        $(".editplanfield").hide();
                        $("#ddl").show();
                        window.location.reload();
                    },
                    data:planid,
                    accept: 'application/json'
                });

Comment: @sormii....In controller I did this...[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult DeletePlan(int planid)
        {
           Plan_S plan = db.Plan_S.Find(planid);
            db.Plan_S.Remove(plan);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { Result="Ok"});
        }

Comment: But it doesn't work....I dont know it's not working.....I think I did no mistake in my logic...Please check my code and advise on that issue....Thanks in advance