# ASP.NET MVC 5 @html helper dropdown populate userform

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view with a dropdown box, here is the start of my view

```
     @model IEnumerable<WebApplication4.Models.CoreSheets>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Iflexcst";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")


@using (Html.BeginForm("Iflexcst", "Costing", FormMethod.Post))
{


        <h2>Enter Dimensions:</h2>

    <h5>
       Select From Standard Sizes:
    </h5> @Html.CheckBox("Standard", false);

        <br>
    <h5> Select Size: </h5>  <br>
    @Html.DropDownList("selectSize", (SelectList)ViewBag.Allsizes);

            <br>
            <label for="NUM">Number of Sets:</label>
    <br>
            <input class="foo" id="NUM" type="text" value=@ViewBag.Quantity name="Quan" /> 

            <br>
    <br>
            <label for="KID">Kamm ID:</label>
    <br>
            <input class="foo" id="KID" type="text" value=@ViewBag.kammid name="kammid" />

    <br>
            <br><label for="KOD">Kamm OD:</label>
    <br>
            <input class="foo" id="KOD" type="text" value=@ViewBag.kammod name="kammod" />

            <br>
    <br>
```

the dropdown box pulls data from a table which stores dimensions, this is my model code...

```
public class AllSizes
{
    [Key]
    public int sizeID { get; set; }

    public string SizeAbb { get; set; }

    public float KammID { get; set; }

    public float KammOD { get; set; }

 public DbSet<AllSizes> AllSizes { get; set; }
```

How would i make it so, when the user selects a size from the dropdown, it then populates my userform, so id want the float KammID from the table to populate...

```
       <label for="KID">Kamm ID:</label>
<br>
        <input class="foo" id="KID" type="text" value=@ViewBag.kammid name="kammid" />

<br>
```

The selectlist is created in my controller,

```
public ActionResult Iflexcst()
{


    CoreSheetsDBContext db = new CoreSheetsDBContext();


    ViewBag.CoreSheets = new SelectList(db.CoreSheets, "sheetID", "Abb");
    ViewBag.FacingSheets = new SelectList(db.FacingSheets, "sheetID", "Abb");
    ViewBag.SpacerSheets = new SelectList(db.SpacerSheets, "sheetID", "Abb");

    ViewBag.Allsizes = new SelectList(db.AllSizes, "sizeID", "SizeAbb");
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why not just bind the property `kammid` to the dropdownlist?

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: You need to show how you construct the `SelectList` that you assign to the `ViewBag.AllSizes` property

Comment: Not sure based on you edit what your trying to do. What is the model in the view? Does it even have a property named `selectSize`?

Comment: Do you mean this? 
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication4.Models.CoreSheets>

When i first started i had this at the top of my view, but now i no longer need it as im getting all my dropdown data from my controller likeeeee


            CoreSheetsDBContext db = new CoreSheetsDBContext();
            ViewBag.Allsizes = new SelectList(db.AllSizes, "sizeID", "SizeAbb");

Comment: Andddddddd within my model of coresheets, i have a few classes for different aspects, like a class to store all my core sheets, then facing sheets ecttttttttttt and no my class for all my sizes doesnt have a "selectsize property" i thought this was more about labeling the dropdownbox. orr retrieving the value.

Comment: Now I'm totally confused. You need to show a bit more of your view.

Comment: haha tell me about it, ive been trying to do it with two dropdowns for so long, but yeah updated the question cheers

Comment: Have you left me Steve?

ive been crawling the questions and came across this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814450/how-to-populate-a-textbox-based-on-dropdown-selection-in-mvc

Which is close to what im trying to achieve except its not getting the model data..